# Remove while iterating leaves element and does not throw Concurrent E

Tags: java

I encountered this piece a of code, that removes item from list while iterating, and yet it does not throw concurrent exception and leaves some items in the list.

Why is that?

Example:.

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        integerList.add(1);
        integerList.add(2);

        for (Integer integer : integerList) {
            removeInteger(integerList, integer);
        }

        System.out.println(integerList.toString()); // prints [2] as it was not removed (while it should be)
    }

    private static void removeInteger(List<Integer> integerList, Integer integer) {
        for (Integer integer1 : integerList) {
            if (integer.equals(integer1)) {
                int index = integerList.indexOf(integer);
                if (index >= 0) {
                    integerList.remove(index);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I change `removeInteger` method to use `Iterator` instead and in `main` I pass a copy of `integerList` everything works as expected.

Comment: @second you are correct, it does throw exception when I add one more element. Care to elaborate why is that?

Comment: Yes, but why does it exhaust them? `remove` still leaves one element left, or is it because it pushes that element to the left? (if you post all of your comments as an answer, including to this one if you have anything, I would accept the answer)

Comment: I removed the comments and put them in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all if you add some more elements to the list it will still fail with a `ConcurrentModificationException.`

For the reason that it does not fail with the posted example, we have to take a look at what happens internally.

If you debug you see that in the posted example, both loops are only iterated once. Removing the element in the inner loop (`removeInteger` method) exhausts both iterators. As there is no further interaction, no error is caused. 'Only' a call of `Iterator#next` after a modification could cause a ConcurrentModificationException.

> Yes, but why does it exhaust them?

Checking the source code of `ArrayList#Itr` we can see that

```
   public boolean hasNext() {
       return cursor != size;
   }
```

only checks a variable called `size`. This variable `size` is a property of the `ArrayList`. When `remove` is called this variable is decremented. Hence the next time `hasNext` is called, the Iterator assumes there are no more new elements.

SideNote: `cursor` points at the next element in the list.